# SQL Query to select element occuring most number of times than others

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to write a SQL Query, to find Mode, that is element occuring more number of times than others.
For eg.

```
    2,2,1,1---->Here, the output should be blank(Both 1 and 2 are occuring twice)

    3,3,3----->Here also, output should be blank(There is no second element)

    3,3,1----->Here the output should be 3.(3's occurence is greater than occurence of 1)
```

These are 3 conditions used for finding it. How can I implement it?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where are you stuck? Without seeing the table structure, sample data, and the expected output according to that sample data, it's pretty difficult to provide help

Answer (score 0):

You can calculate the number of values, the one with the highest frequency and also filter on the number of values:

```
select x.*
from (select val,
             count(*) as cnt,
             row_number() over (order by count(*) desc ) as seqnum,
             count(*) over () as num_vals
             count(*) over (partition by count(*)) as cnt_cnt
      from table 
      group by val
     ) x
where cnt_cnt = 1 and seqnum = 1 and num_vals > 1;
```

Actually, you can do this with a `having` clause and `order by`:

```
select val
from (select val, count(*) as cnt,
             count(*) over () as num_values
      from table 
      group by val
     ) v
where num_values > 1
order by cnt desc;
```